# Fatal error: Class 'Fris_Socialbuttons_Helper_Data' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\Mage.php on line 547

Tags: fatal-error, magento1.9.3, social-buttons

I am trying to install **Fris Social share** in my `Magento 1.9.3` store.

I am getting the following error after installation:

> Fatal error: Class 'Fris_Socialbuttons_Helper_Data' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\Mage.php on line 547

I have `disabled` Compilation in **admin>system>tool>compilation** its working fine, but when I `enable` Compilation, it shows above error.

Following code in `app\code\local\Fris\Socialbuttons\etc\config.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <Fris_Socialbuttons>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </Fris_Socialbuttons>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <blocks>
            <fris_socialbuttons>
                <class>Fris_Socialbuttons_Block</class>
            </fris_socialbuttons>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <fris_socialbuttons>
                <class>Fris_Socialbuttons_Helper</class>
            </fris_socialbuttons>
        </helpers>
    </global>

    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <socialbuttons module="Fris_Socialbuttons">
                    <file>fris/socialbuttons/socialbuttons.xml</file>
                </socialbuttons>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>

    <default>
        <design>
            <socialbuttons module="fris_socialbuttons">
                <font_icon_facebook>fa fa-facebook</font_icon_facebook>
                <font_icon_google_plus>fa fa-google-plus</font_icon_google_plus>
                <font_icon_linkedin>fa fa-linkedin</font_icon_linkedin>
                <font_icon_pinterest>fa fa-pinterest</font_icon_pinterest>
                <font_icon_twitter>fa fa-twitter</font_icon_twitter>
                <font_icon_twitter_follow></font_icon_twitter_follow>
                <twitter_handle></twitter_handle>
                <button_container_style></button_container_style>
                <button_style></button_style>
            </socialbuttons>
        </design>
    </default>

</config>
```

`app\code\local\Fris\Socialbuttons\Helper\Data.php`

```
class Fris_Socialbuttons_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

How to fix this error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you defined `<helpers>` inside `global` tag? Show your full config.xml code

Comment: @userpk : Thank you for your reply am updated the code

Comment: After the installation of this module, did you re-run the compile?

Comment: @PavanKumar How can i `re-run` compile

Comment: through admin, system-tools-compile-rerun. I m not sure about the path. But, if you add any new module when the compilation is enable, then u need to rerun the compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your full xml like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Fris_Socialbuttons>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </Fris_Socialbuttons>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <socialbuttons>
                <class>Fris_Socialbuttons_Block</class>
            </socialbuttons>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <socialbuttons>
                <class>Fris_Socialbuttons_Helper</class>
            </socialbuttons>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <socialbuttons module="socialbuttons">
                    <file>fris/socialbuttons/socialbuttons.xml</file>
                </socialbuttons>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <default>
        <design>
            <socialbuttons module="socialbuttons">
                <font_icon_facebook>fa fa-facebook</font_icon_facebook>
                <font_icon_google_plus>fa fa-google-plus</font_icon_google_plus>
                <font_icon_linkedin>fa fa-linkedin</font_icon_linkedin>
                <font_icon_pinterest>fa fa-pinterest</font_icon_pinterest>
                <font_icon_twitter>fa fa-twitter</font_icon_twitter>
                <font_icon_twitter_follow></font_icon_twitter_follow>
                <twitter_handle></twitter_handle>
                <button_container_style></button_container_style>
                <button_style></button_style>
            </socialbuttons>
        </design>
    </default>
</config>
```

Comment: Sorry Aman Alam  not working

Comment: i have just posted full xml you should try that after updating xml don't forget to clear caching

Comment: Same error sorry

Comment: Do you have compiler enable?

Comment: Yes i did......

Comment: disable it and try

Answer (score 1):

try changing this part of your code

```
<socialbuttons module="fris_socialbuttons">
```

Try changing it to your helper alias:

```
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <socialbuttons module="fris_socialbuttons">
                <file>fris/socialbuttons/socialbuttons.xml</file>
            </socialbuttons>
        </updates>
    </layout>
```

Comment: Sorry not working

Comment: AM update your code and clear cache in `var\cache` folder and run it showing same error

Comment: Can you please update your full code

Comment: disable and re-compile again

Comment: Okay just a min

Comment: Same error @userpk